# Memory deallocation for char pointer

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

Part from my code:

```
class Menuitem
{
private:
    char* text;

    friend class Menu;
};

class Menu
{
private:
    char* title;
    Menuitem* items;
    int identation = 0;
    int amount = 0;
};
```

If I will do `delete[] items`, will it also safely delete `text` that saved in `items`? Or do I need to delete them separetely?

Comment: You need to do exactly one `delete` for every `new` you previously did.  In particular, `delete` will not automatically delete any sub-allocations for you (you'll need to handle those yourself, typically in your class's destructor-method).  Better yet, avoid `new` and `delete` entirely whenever possible, and use e.g. `std::string` instead.  Your life will be much less painful that way.

Comment: In case, you really have to use `char*`, use smart pointers.

Comment: @Dr_Cringe At least you could write a destructor for the class Menuitem. What is the problem?

Comment: Since C++11 there is no need for new/delete. Use std::shared_ptr<MenuItem> together with std:string.

Comment: I have a hard time seeing what `std::shared_ptr` would bring over `std::unique_ptr` @Werner

Comment: @Rosme From the reference to `delete[]` in the question and the name `items` which is pluralized, I think `items` is means to point to an array. So `std::vector` is probably better than either smart pointer type here.

Comment: std::unique_ptr is also fine when you don't intend to hold multiple references to the same object @Rosme

Comment: @François The following would also allow a forward declaration 
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MenuItem>> items;

Answer (score 3):

> If I will do `delete[] items`, will it also safely delete text that saved in `items`?

Not with the posted code.

> Or do I need to `delete` them separetely?

Yes.

If you are attempting to learn how memory allcoation/deallocation works, it's good to understand the issues and learn how to use `new` and `delete` properly.
It is essential to know about [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and adhere to it when you are managing dynamic memory.

If you are trying to get an application to working condition, it will be better to avoid using raw pointers. Use containers from the standard library.

```
class Menuitem
{
  private:
    std::string text;  // No char*

    friend class Menu;
};

class Menu
{
  private:
    std::string title;  // No char*
    std::vector<Menuitem> items; // No MenuItem*
    int identation = 0;
    int amount = 0;
};
```

Then, you have fewer problems to worry about in application code.